# Laravel Filament Wizard | No property found for validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm using the Filament admin panel for Laravel and I've encountered an issue with the Wizard component in the form. When I try to proceed to the next step in the wizard, I'm getting the error: "No property found for validation: [file_name]".

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I have a CategoryApplication model that has a relationship with CategoryStep.
In the CustomCreateCategoryApplicationSteps page, I'm trying to dynamically generate steps in the wizard based on the CategoryStep related to the CategoryApplication.
Each step in the wizard should have a TextInput component where the user can input a file name.

My code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\CategoryApplicationStepResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\CategoryApplicationStepResource;
use App\Models\CategoryApplication;
use App\Models\CategoryApplicationStep;
use App\Models\CategoryStep;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\Page;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Wizard;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Filament\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Checkbox;
use Filament\Forms\Components\FileUpload;




class CustomCreateCategoryApplicationSteps extends Page
{
    protected static string $resource = CategoryApplicationStepResource::class;

    protected static string $view = 'filament.resources.category-application-step-resource.pages.custom-create-category-application-steps';

    protected static ?string $label = 'Apply Category';

    protected static ?string $title = 'Apply Category';

    public $categorySteps;

    public $originalCategorySteps;

    public function mount($record): void
    {
        $categoryApplication = CategoryApplication::findOrFail($record);
        $category = $categoryApplication->category;
        $this->categorySteps = $category->categorySteps;

        //dd($this->categorySteps);
        //$this->form->fill();
    }


    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $wizardSteps = [];

        foreach ($this->categorySteps as $categoryStep) {
            $wizardSteps[] = Wizard\Step::make($categoryStep->step_title)
                ->schema([
                    TextInput::make('file_name')
                        ->id("category-step".$categoryStep->id)
                        ->label('Upload File')
                        ->required(),
                ]);
        }

        return $form
            ->schema([Wizard::make($wizardSteps)]);
    }

    public function getFormActions()
    {
        return [
            Action::make('save')
                ->label(__('filament-panels::resources/pages/create-record.form.actions.create.label'))
                ->submit('save')
        ];
    }

    public function save(): void
    {
        $data = $this->form->getState();

        foreach ($data['categorySteps'] as $step) {
            CategoryApplicationStep::create([
                'category_step_id' => $step['id'],
                'category_application_id' => $this->record,
                'file_name' => $step['file_name'],
            ]);
        }

        Notification::make()
            ->success()
            ->title("Success!")
            ->send();
    }





}
```

When I try to navigate to the next step in the wizard, I encounter the error. I suspect it might be related to how I'm naming the TextInput components or how the form state is being managed, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any insights on how to resolve it?

I tried to get around the problem by doing unique naming but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. I was manage to fix it by adding the property.

Add the `$file_name property` just below the public `$originalCategorySteps`;

Your code will look like this:

```
public $originalCategorySteps;
public $file_name;
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work